# Concatenate results of commands in Bash

Tags: bash

I was looking for a single one-liner to produce a line with all data:

These four [separate] commands produce the info I need, but I don't know how to concatenate them into a single line:

```
$ cat /proc/cpuinfo | grep "model name" | sed -n -e 's/^.*: //p'
ARMv6-compatible processor rev 7 (v6l)
$ lscpu | grep "CPU(s):" | awk '{print $2}'
1
$ lscpu | grep "CPU min MHz:" | awk '{print $4}'
700.0000
$ lscpu | grep "CPU max MHz:" | awk '{print $4}'
1000.0000
```

And I wanted to get:

```
ARMv6-compatible processor rev 7 (v6l) x1 @700 MHz (max @1000 MHz)
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

just using **echo**

```
echo $(cat /proc/cpuinfo | grep "model name" | sed -n -e 's/^.*: //p') \
   x$(lscpu | grep "CPU(s):" | awk '{print $2}') \
   @$(lscpu | grep "CPU min MHz:" | awk '{print $4}') \
   '( max' $(lscpu | grep "CPU max MHz:" | awk '{print $4}') ')'
```

By the way, you could use just `grep "model name" /proc/cpuinfo` instead of `cat /proc/cpuinfo | grep "model name"`

Answer (score 1):

One way.

```
paste -d ' ' <(awk '/^model name/{sub(/.+: /,"");print;exit}' /proc/cpuinfo) <(lscpu | awk '/CPU min MHz:/{printf " (max @%d MHz) ", $4} /CPU max MHz:/{printf "@%d MHz",  $4} /^CPU\(s\):/{printf "x%s ", $2}')
```

Comment: How can I fix the reversed frequencies? With this command I get `ARMv6-compatible processor rev 7 (v6l) x1 @1000 MHz (max @700 MHz)`.

Comment: Change min to max and max to min inside the `/  /` in awk, the order matters, min should come first before max